# Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize microphone in wired earset; Windows 10 does

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones, microphone, apple

My laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 has only one socket for both mic and headphones; when I plug my headphones ([Apple Earpods](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug)) with the mic, headphones work fine but the microphone is not found. In Windows 10 it all works fine without even doing anything. The microphone built in to the laptop chassis works fine all the time.

```
$ sudo lshw -c sound

  *-multimedia         

   description: Audio device
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
   version: 21
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
   resources: irq:138 memory:df128000-df12bfff memory:df100000-df10ffff
```